# Find angle between space diagonal and one of its edges of cube with unit side length.?

Tags: geometry, vectors

Q - consider a cube in $\mathbb R^3$ with unit side length and one vertex at the origin. Find the angle between the space diagonal of this cube and one of its edges.

my solution/attempt is  attached, please correct if needed.[image]

Comment: Yes it is correct.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @MathLover thanks for the response. Btw is there a way to solve the similar Q using matrix?

Comment: @Axel thanks for the response.

Comment: @GaurangChauhan it is the same thing as in below answer. You can write vectors as matrices and take dot product.

Comment: @MathLover okay I will try. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is right. Alternatively, since you marked it with the `vectors` tag, you might want to use dot product. Starting from origin, the diagonal is $(1,1,1)$. The side is $(1,0,0)$ (or $(0,1,0)$ or $(0,0,1)$). Then $$(1,1,1)\cdot(1,0,0)=1=|(1,1,1)|\cdot |(1,0,0)|\cdot\cos\theta=\sqrt3 \cdot 1\cdot\cos\theta$$
Therefore $$\theta=\arccos\frac1{\sqrt 3}$$
This is the same angle.

Comment: yes, completely understandable. Thanks for the answer and response.

Comment: @Andrie can we get the same answer using a matrix approach? Just give hints if possible

Comment: I'm not sure what the matrix approach is for this problem.

Comment: @Andrie okay, no problem. Still thanks